# Ping Local unity3d Player from the server?

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, unity-game-engine, ping

In my game, there are different screens have placed. The screens will show dynamic text. The text, I want to change through my server where I have python.

Now I want that I could find a way to update the text  **whenever I required** but from the server side. Is there any way available that I get my player URL (located in a local system) so that I send data to that URL and I write a function in my player which update my screen text data.

In simple manner I want to ping my local player from my server.

How do i receive call from the a server and write appropriate service to receive its response?